# Glitchy white screen after the latest ubuntu 20.04 software update

Tags: linux, asus-laptop, ubuntu-20.04, asus-rog-zephyrus

After installing the latest software updates on my ubuntu 20.04, the system asked me to restart it, and it never opened after the restart. Instead, I get a glitchy white screen whenever I try to open Ubuntu from the boot menu as I have a dual boot Linux and windows.

[image: the glitchy white screen]

My Laptop is Asus ROG Zephyrus G14
What I tried:-

I thought it was an issue with the latest version of Nvidia drivers, so purged all the Nvidia drivers using `apt purge nvidia* libnvidia*` from the root menu terminal of recovery mode.
"It still did not work."

Then I changed the grub file from the boot menu and replaced `quick splash` with `nomodeset`
Ubuntu did open but the graphics card was not running, I tried installing previous versions of Nvidia drivers and restarting the system, and every time I ended up on the same glitchy screen.

I need the Nvidia driver running on my ubuntu 20.04 and

I have no clue what's wrong, Somebody please help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reinstall the nvidia-driver?

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-xxx
```

where xxx is the version of your nvidia-driver. You can find the version of your nvidia-driver from https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx

```
sudo reboot
```